# How to enable CORS in Play Framework 2.5.9 in Java

Tags: java, playframework

I had a hard time here enabling CORS in my Play Framework Project. I tried to use my api(i made a html file with javascript on it). it Keeps returning like this :

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:9000/generateToken. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

I dont know what to do already, ive followed Play's Documentation and it doesnt seem to work.

These are my Filters.java:

```
import com.google.inject.Inject;
import play.http.HttpFilters;
import play.mvc.EssentialAction;
import play.mvc.EssentialFilter;
import play.filters.cors.CORSFilter;

public class Filters extends EssentialFilter implements HttpFilters {

    @Inject
    private CORSFilter corsFilter;


    @Override
    public EssentialAction apply(EssentialAction next) {
        return corsFilter.asJava().apply(next);
    }

    @Override
    public EssentialFilter[] filters() {
        EssentialFilter[] result = new EssentialFilter[1];
        result[0] = this;

        return result;
    }
}
```

then this is my configuration :

```
play.filters.enabled += "play.filters.cors.CORSFilter"
//
play.http.filters = "Filters"
play.filters.cors {
  # allow all paths
  pathPrefixes = ["/"]
  # allow all origins
  allowedOrigins = null
  allowedHttpMethods = ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"]
  # allow all headers
  allowedHttpHeaders = null
}
```

Is there anyone who can answer this correctly? T_T T_T

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of filters() is off :

```
@Override
public EssentialFilter[] filters() {
    final List<EssentialFilter> filters = new ArrayList<>();
    filters.add(corsFilter.asJava());
    return filters.toArray(new EssentialFilter[0]);
}
```

The Filters class just needs to implement HttpFilters